# Declaring a very large vector of ints?

Tags: c++, vector

Is there a way to do this in C++ without having things crash on runtime?

Right now I am declaring

```
vector<vector<int> > myvec(veclength);
```

How can I crank up veclength as high as it will go (properly)? Even at 10^7 it crashes when I should have more than enough computer memory.

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/max_size/ and test what the max_size is on your machine. The key here is that the vector size limit is [reduced as the size of vector elements increase](http://ntcoder.com/bab/2008/08/27/whats-the-size-limit-of-a-vector/) - and since you have a `vector` of `vector` of `int`, the size of the outer vector is likely to be quite limited.

Comment: What is the nature of the crash? How much memory do you have, and what is `sizeof (vector<int>)` on your system? Are you building for 32 or 64 bits (or something else)?

Comment: @John Smith - I wouldn't be so quick to accept questions until you've tested them - perhaps you should simply upvote helpful comments until you're sure of the solution - that way you may even get more input on the question.

Comment: So, to be clear John Smith - you got your program working with `veclength = 10^7` ? Because I could not in a simple test program. (See edits below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should take take approximately 250 MiB of space<sup>1</sup> (or less, depending on architecture) so memory definitely isn’t the problem here, and neither should `max_size`, which would be in the order of 10<sup>17</sup> (≈ <sup>2<sup>64</sup></sup>∕<sub>8+8+8</sub>).

I should mention that I corroborated these calculations by looking at the implementations of `std::vector`in GCC' libstdc++ and LLVM's libc++, and by testing on a live system. The calculated values correspond 1:1 to the real implementations, and the OP’s code works flawlessly with `veclength = 10e7`.

I therefore conclude that the real cause is elsewhere.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Calculated by approximating the size of each individual vector by three 64 bit integers to denote begin pointer, size and capacity respectively, and assuming that an empty vector has a default capacity of 0. Actual implementations may differ but probably not by much.

Comment: @John That’s possible but I am still convinced that the real issue is elsewhere and is simply masked until you get to a high number of values. I have in the meantime verified the `max_size` limits for both 32 bit and 64 bit architectures and they are *definitely* able to hold that many elements. Likewise, memory is definitely not a constraint here.

Comment: Any idea what the problem might be? As far as I can tell, the program's logic is fairly solid

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have mad respect for you man, but this answer reeks of lack of research. Things don't always work out as they should in theory, and `Vector` really is limited by by both the std::vector implementation and limitations on the machine running the program. See the links in my answer, and the edit which gives an actual example showing a limit very close to what the asker posted. (10^9 for int, much less for higher element sizes)

Comment: @John Sorry, no inkling. I suspect (!) that at some part of the code you invoke undefined behaviour and this goes haywire for large inputs only. But it’s hard to hypothesise about this without seing the code.

Comment: Actually I figured out my problem. Turns out for small values, I never experienced this particular issue; for large values I was going over bounds on my vector (it was a bug that didn't show up for small values). Things work now and your answer was correct.

Comment: @Alain I actually tested it after doing the calculations. But you *should* be able to reason about these things using calculations if you know enough about the implementations, and my tests corroborate the calculations. FWIW I’m using GCC but I also checked clang.

Comment: Bear in mind that `max_size` is an upper bound, and doesn't guarantee that all sizes smaller than that are supported at runtime. Most so-called 64-bit systems give you a virtual memory space considerably smaller than 64 bits; and even a true 64-bit system in unlikely to have petabytes of available memory (for a few years at least).

Comment: @Mike Yes but the actual size of the vector is nowhere near this limit anyway. It’s a measly few hundred MiB.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Does this explain the results of the tests in my edits?

Answer (score 0):

See [std::vector::max_size](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/max_size/)

> Returns the maximum number of elements that the vector can hold.
>
> This is the maximum potential size the container can reach due to known system or library implementation limitations, but the container is by no means guaranteed to be able to reach that size: it can still fail to allocate storage at any point before that size is reached.

The gotcha here is that the vector size limit is only a constant for a given vector type. It is **not a constant** across all vector types - it changes based on the type of element the vector holds. This is because [vectors are spaced to store all elements back-to-back in contiguous memory](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). Therefore, the max size is reduced as the size of vector elements increase.

Note that you did not declare a `vector<int>` (where `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes), but a `vector<vector<int>>` (where `sizeof(vector<int>)` is 28 bytes - at least for GCC 4.1).

This makes the maximum size of your (outer) vector probably much smaller than you were expecting.

---

Here is a small program you can run locally that outputs the max size of a vector with a given type:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Max elements inserted into a vector having elements of size '" 
              << sizeof( std::vector<int> ) << "' is: "
              << std::vector<std::vector<int> >().max_size() << std::endl;
}
```

On my 2012 PC, a `vector<int>` (`int` has size 4) has a max size of 1,073,741,823 (~10^9).
A `vector<vector<int>>` (`vector<int>` has size 28) (which you are using) reports a significantly reduced max size to 153,391,689

Here is a variety of outputs for `vector`s of `char`, `int` (or 32-bit pointer), `double` (or 64-bit pointer), and `vector<vector<int>>`:

```
Max elements inserted into a vector having elements of size '1'  is: 4,294,967,295
Max elements inserted into a vector having elements of size '4'  is: 1,073,741,823
Max elements inserted into a vector having elements of size '8'  is:   536,870,911
Max elements inserted into a vector having elements of size '28' is:   153,391,689
```

---

**Proposed Solution**

If you change your data structure to be a `vector` of `*vector<int>` (i.e. vector **pointers**), then you'll be able to store many more elements because your nested vectors aren't all being squished into the same set of contiguous allocated memory anymore. Of course, this could have knock-on performance effects and/or change a variety of your business logic, so you may choose to go with a different approach.

---

**2023 Update:**

Now when I run the above code, I get:

```
Max elements inserted into a vector having elements of size '24' is:
                                           384,307,168,202,282,325 (~2^58 or ~10^17)
```

So while it like in time the `size<vector<int>>` has been reduced from 28 -> 24, and the overall max_size has also grown significantly (likely as a result of switching from testing on x86 -> x64 architecture)

Comment: –1. I don’t believe this is the correct answer – see mine for details, `max_size` is big enough.

Comment: `sizeof` a vector is fixed regardless of the number of elements in that vector. Thus, the outer vector's `max_size` will not take into account the number of ints in the inner vector.

Comment: I’m surprised that the size of the vector is 28. This is a very (!) odd implementation. I’m too lazy to look at where exactly GCC 4.1 f*cks up but this number should definitely be the lowest bound, contrary to what you said, because a straight-forward implementation (and those that I looked at!) use *less* memory, thus allow more elements. That codepad crashes with this code is not surprising and irrelevant, since it’s working in a very restricted environment. And the OP has already confirmed that the error is, indeed, elsewhere.

Comment: @Alain: do not forget that most of the websites proposing to run your code allow only limited CPU and memory resources. And especially in C and C++, most likely run into a sandbox or VM for security reasons.

Comment: This answer is still getting mixed ratings 10 years later, so I've updated to emphasise the key takeaway and be less confusing.